Analog of Leibniz integral rule on $\mathbb{C}$

Let $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{C})$. If $f$ has compact support, then a
solution to the equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}u = f$
is given by $$u(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\mathbb{C}}
 \frac{f(w+z)}{w} d \overline{w} \wedge dw.$$


I want to check that this is true, but I don't know how. So, I have that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} u(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} \int_{\mathbb{C}}
 \frac{f(w+z)}{w} d \overline{w} \wedge dw$. But is this equal to $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} (\frac{f(w+z)}{w}) d \overline{w} \wedge dw$ ?
Is there an analog of Leibniz integral rule or something? Thanks!
Edit: In "From Holomorphic Functions to Complex Manifolds" - Klaus Fritzsche, Hans Grauert (p. 306) it says that we apply formulas for the derivative of parametric integrals but I know this for $\mathbb{R}$, for $\mathbb{C}$ I don't know of such formula...

Are you aware of the generalized version of Cauchy's integral formula, namely Cauchy-Pompeiu's formula, and the related proof (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Generalizations) ?

@Abezhiko yes but how this help?

Maybe you should use the cartesian coordinates decomposition, i.e. $\partial_{\bar{z}}=\partial_x-i\partial_y$. (upto a half factor).

@MathematicalPhysicist yes but still don't understand how the conclusion results

@MathLearner. In the present case, the domain of integration doesn't depend on $\bar{z}$, so that you can move the derivative inside the integral straightfowardly. After a translation by $z$ through a change of variable, use the fact that the Cauchy kernel is the fundamental solution / Green's function of Von Neumann's $\bar{\partial}$-problem, i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}} \frac{1}{2\pi iz} = \delta^{(2)}(z)$.

@Abezhiko I still don't understand why if domain doesn't depend on $\overline{z}$ then I can move the derivative inside the integral

@MathLearner. Because the "additional" terms in Leibniz's integral formula come from differentiation of the integral boundaries, when they are dependent on the variable with respect to which the derivative is performed.
